# How to get all the pdf files avalable in interanal storage of iphone in react native using native module

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, react-native

I wanted to know how can i access the list of .pdf present in the iphone internal storage in react native native modules using objective c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement simple native module in your xcode project to return list of files from the document directory of your app to react native e.g.:

**FileList.h**

```c
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface FileList : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

**FileList.m**

```c
#import "FileList.h"

@implementation FileList

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(FileList)

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(get:(NSString *)extension callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
    NSString *documentsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject;
    NSArray *files = [NSFileManager.defaultManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDir error:nil];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH %@", extension];
    NSArray *filtered = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    callback(@[filtered]);
}
@end
```

How to use:

```js
import {
    ...
    NativeModules,
} from 'react-native';

...

NativeModules.FileList.get('pdf', list => {
    print(list); // Prints: file1.pdf, file2.pdf etc.
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer one more question could we search the pdf outside the app sandbox in ios means in every directory present in the iphone storage if we can then how to do it ?

Comment: @hassanmustafa For this you can access to Files app that provides shared documents from other apps, see - https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/